# Weird "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space"

Tags: java, image, out-of-memory

Today i did simple Java application, what should just load some .png files to memory (total space of these files is ~7mb), but it makes this weird error:

(My tiny command: java -Xmx1024m -jar dist/PNGImageLoader.jar)

> Loaded image (0) images/image_01000111100000011000000110100000 Loaded
>   image (1) images/image_00000101010101101101000111111101 Loaded image
>   (2) images/image_01001110110011110011111001000000 Loaded image (3)
>   images/image_01001111000111010110101101001111 Loaded image (4)
>   images/image_00011100000011100011001011011100 Loaded image (5)
>   images/image_01010010001010001010110110110110 Loaded image (6)
>   images/image_01101100010001000001000110101111 Loaded image (7)
>   images/image_01010111011011101010101110100010 Loaded image (8)
>   images/image_01101101110100001011001011101100 Loaded image (9)
>   images/image_01100010111110011011100001000011 Loaded image (10)
>   images/image_00011111011000111101101111101111 Loaded image (11)
>   images/image_00000100111001010110101001110001 Loaded image (12)
>   images/image_01000001100111011101101011011011 Loaded image (13)
>   images/image_01100111000010000001011101111001 Loaded image (14)
>   images/image_01101000011011000001111010001100 Loaded image (15)
>   images/image_00010010110100001011000111111000 Loaded image (16)
>   images/image_00111100111011101101101001000101 Loaded image (17)
>   images/image_01111110001010111100011000000110 Loaded image (18)
>   images/image_00010111101011100011101101101000 Loaded image (19)
>   images/image_00101000001111110110000110101101 Loaded image (20)
>   images/image_01110101110000010000000000001001 Loaded image (21)
>   images/image_01001000101010101010000010100011 Loaded image (22)
>   images/image_00110111100001110011010011011001 Loaded image (23)
>   images/image_00001010001001000001101001001011 Loaded image (24)
>   images/image_00101111000110011000110011111000 Loaded image (25)
>   images/image_00101100010101000011001101010111 Loaded image (26)
>   images/image_01101111101000010111011000011010 Loaded image (27)
>   images/image_00111011111100000111100000000011 Loaded image (28)
>   images/image_01100100000101111111001000111101 Loaded image (29)
>   images/image_01001101110111111011000101000011 Loaded image (30)
>   images/image_00110010111010000111111011100101 Loaded image (31)
>   images/image_00111001110100011100101111111011 Loaded image (32)
>   images/image_01100011101111010111110110001111 Loaded image (33)
>   images/image_01000000110111000000010100010011 Loaded image (34)
>   images/image_00110101000001001101100010101001 Loaded image (35)
>   images/image_01001101011011010110100110111010 Loaded image (36)
>   images/image_00010111010100110100011111110101 Loaded image (37)
>   images/image_01011111011001111010000000111000 Loaded image (38)
>   images/image_00110001100110011111000010110001 Loaded image (39)
>   images/image_01110101010001111001011000000011 Exception in thread
>   "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space    at
>   java.awt.image.DataBufferByte.(DataBufferByte.java:92)  at
>   java.awt.image.ComponentSampleModel.createDataBuffer(ComponentSampleModel.java:415)
>     at java.awt.image.Raster.createWritableRaster(Raster.java:941)  at
>   javax.imageio.ImageTypeSpecifier.createBufferedImage(ImageTypeSpecifier.java:1073)
>     at javax.imageio.ImageReader.getDestination(ImageReader.java:2896)
>     at
>   com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.readImage(PNGImageReader.java:1280)
>     at
>   com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.read(PNGImageReader.java:1577)
>     at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1448)    at
>   javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1308)     at
>   pngimageloader.Images.loadImage(Images.java:22)   at
>   pngimageloader.Images.getImage(Images.java:33)    at
>   pngimageloader.Images.getAllImages(Images.java:43)    at
>   pngimageloader.PNGImageLoader.main(PNGImageLoader.java:15)

Here is my PNGImageLoader.java class,

```
package pngimageloader;

public class PNGImageLoader {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Images images = new Images();
        images.getAllImages("images/");
    }
}
```

Here is Images.java class..

```
package pngimageloader;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.HashMap;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Images {

    HashMap images;

    Images() {
        images = new HashMap();
    }

    BufferedImage loadImage(String path) {
        try {
            return ImageIO.read(new File(path));
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            System.out.println(exception.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
            return null;
        }
    }

    BufferedImage getImage(String path) {
        BufferedImage image = (BufferedImage) images.get(path);
        if (image == null) {
            image = loadImage(path);
            images.put(path, image);
        }
        return image;
    }

    void getAllImages(String path) {
        File files = new File(path);
        int i = 0;
        for (File file : files.listFiles()) {
            getImage(file.getPath());
            System.out.println("Loaded image (" + i + ") " + file.getPath());
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm unprofessional, but i think it's really weird.
Thanks in advance for help, Patrick.

Comment: How is it weird? You're loading a bunch of images from the disk in memory. The memory is limited. So it throws an OutOfMemoryError because it doesn't have enough memory to load all your images.

Comment: @JBNizet apparently what's weird is that the total size of these images is merely ~7mb whereas [the default max heap size as considerably greater](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gc-ergonomics.html). Unless, of course, a value other than the default is used...

Comment: It's weird for me, becouse total space of these files is something like 7mb, and i have free 2gb of my ram.
My tiny command: java -Xmx128m -jar dist/PNGImageLoader.jar

Comment: Or could be that the total size is actually greater than 7mb... Or more files than intended are loaded... Or images are loaded multiple times... Or other memory exhausting operations surround the images loading... Well, that's quite a lot to check, @PerdutaPatrick .

Comment: @PerdutaPatrick well try using `-Xmx1G` instead of `128m`.

Comment: @PerdutaPatrick 128mb is a barrier broken more easily than one can think.

Comment: Part of the problem is that PNG is a compressed file format. So the size of the files in pixels once loaded into the BufferedImage may be far larger than the 7mb.  I just created a 1000x1000 solid color image in photoshop (1M pixels x 3 bytes per pixel) but the size of the PNG file is only 1kb.

Comment: You assigned 128 MB max to the whole JVM heap. That leaves little room for the images (much less than your total 2GB of ram). And although they only take 7 MBs on the disk in a PNG compressed form, they take much more space in memory, where they're uncompressed and represented in a renderable way.

Comment: @yair, here have you your 1G :P
http://pastebin.com/8FgxS5Su

Comment: My phone has 1 GB of free memory (and 70 GB free storage). If you machine doesn't have more memory when it is doing a memory intensive test, get a machine which is sutable for the job.

Comment: @JBNizet, i tryed this with 1024mb max in my JVM heap too, and this is still crushing.

Comment: Increasing the memory will only make the problem appear later, when more images are loaded. Why do you need all these images in memory at once? What are you trying to achieve? Why not process them one by one?

Comment: If you don't believe, you can check it yourself, here is my project :) https://www.dropbox.com/s/d7qizducl4mjm3b/PNGImageLoader.zip

Comment: We do believe, and explained what the problem is. I only opened one of the image. It's black and white only, with large horizontal bands. That makes it extremely small when compressed as PNG. But its size is 2500x3200 pixels, which is huge. To represent all those pixels in memory, 4 bytes are needed per pixel, which makes a total of 32 MBs per image in memory. Multiply that by the number of loaded images (39 in your listing), and you're already over 1GB of memory. Process the images one by one.

Answer (score 0):

As GSP pointed out your small files can be expanded to lots of memory.
Things is you most probably should not keep the images in memory, there is almost never a reason to do so.
Just use some sort of streaming stuff, dependending on what you want to do.